# Kotlin: SOAP XML Array object is empty

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am trying to consume soap response using kotlin data classes. My kotlin classes return success response for Strings but Where array i see it as empty.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:response xmlns:ns="http://google.com">
            <ns:return xmlns:ax231="http://io.java/xsd" xmlns:ax233="http://google.com/xsd" xmlns:ax235="http://rmi.java/xsd" xmlns:ax238="http://http://google.com/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Response">
                <ax238:type>M</ax238:type>
                <ax238:serviceBenefitArray xsi:type="ax238:ServiceBenefitArray">
                    <ax238:serviceBenefit xsi:type="ax238:ServiceBenefit">
                        <ax238:indicator>Y</ax238:indicator>
                    </ax238:serviceBenefit>
                    <ax238:serviceBenefit xsi:type="ax238:ServiceBenefit">
                        <ax238:indicator>N</ax238:indicator>
                    </ax238:serviceBenefit>
                </ax238:serviceBenefitArray>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am able to acces `type=M` But serviceBenefitArray.serviceBenefit is coming as empty array.

Below are my kotlin classes

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "Response",
    propOrder = ["type", serviceBenefitArray]
)
class Response
{
    @XmlElementRef(
        name = "serviceBenefitArray",
        namespace = "http://google.com.com/xsd",
        type = JAXBElement::class,
        required = false
    )
    var serviceBenefitArray: JAXBElement<ServiceBenefitArray>? = null

    @XmlElementRef(
        name = "type",
        namespace = "http://google.com/xsd",
        type = JAXBElement::class,
        required = false
    )
    var type: JAXBElement<String>? = null
}



@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ServiceBenefitArray", propOrder = ["serviceBenefit"])
data class ServiceBenefitArray(
    @XmlElement(
        name = "serviceBenefit",
    )
    var serviceBenefit: Array<ServiceBenefit> = emptyArray()
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.